# Accessing whole Iphone addressbook

Tags: iphone, abaddressbook

I am developing an application to backup the whole address book into amazon s3,but i cant able to find any direct iphone api to get the whole address book into any data structure.

I tried the following code,to write the address book array to a file in document directory

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *addressPath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"AddressBook.plist"];


ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();

NSMutableArray *allPeople = [[[(NSArray*) ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook)autorelease]mutableCopy]autorelease];

[allPeople writeToFile:addressPath atomically:YES];
```

But the problem is file is not getting created in document directory....

Any suggestions appreciated....

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not 100% sure, but Accessing the entire addressbook at once probably is not allowed. Apple has the AddressBookPeoplePicker for a reason, though picking everyone in the AddressBook one person at a time would be a pain.

You may be able to set up a loop to run through the address book programatically. Then add it to your own NSMutableArray.

Comment: Thanks for your response....yes ,only way is to traversing through whole addressbook

Answer (score 0):

You would require this function: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABPersonRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007210

An Array of all the people is returned. Read the documentation for more. Best of Luck!